# Counting the quantity by using the Steam Api

Tags: php, api, steam

I was messing around with the steam API and I found out that I was not able to get the quantity of my items. Lets say I have item A 2 times, it does not show the picture just 1 time with the quantity set to "2", but instead it shows the item twice with the quantity set to 1.

This is the part I use to get the inventory.

```
    $backpackURL = "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=" .     $APIkey . "&SteamID=" . $profile . "&format=json";
    $schemaURL = "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetSchema/v0001/?key=" . $APIkey . "&language=en";

    $userBackpack = json_decode(file_get_contents($backpackURL), true);
    $itemSchema = json_decode(file_get_contents($schemaURL), true);

    $backpack_items = $userBackpack['result'];
    $schema_items = $itemSchema['result'];
```

And here I list all the items:

```
  foreach($backpack_items['items'] as $ind=>$backpack_items){
                $id =  $backpack_items['id'];
                $defindex = $backpack_items['defindex'];
                $name = getItemName($schema_items, $defindex, $image_url);
                $quantity = $backpack_items['quantity'];
                $inventory = $backpack_items['inventory'];

                echo '
                    $tmp[] = $backpack_items; print_r($tmp)
                ';
            }
```

Comment: Then I suggest you append `$backpack_items` to an array and filter out the duplicate values and merge them to a single array. However you probably copy pasted the code (notably due to the comments) and don't know how to change it.

Comment: Then I suggest you trim your question down to specifics. There are 2 variables that 'link' to your question. This is probably `$id` and specificly `$quantity` the rest is obsolete information. Instead of that entire code **inside** the loop, do `$tmp[] = $backpack_items; print_r($tmp);`. Remove the obsolete results or post it via pastebin or some sort.

Comment: According to the output, I don't see any duplicate id's so it would be infact a unique item. However, you could merge the results on the name if they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no ID to see if there are any duplicates, you can try to merge them by name.

By reading this code, it first creates a copy of the main array.
I loop over the main array, then again over the copy. So for each value of the main array, a complete cycle of the array is done again for values to compare against.

Since it is expected that there is atleast 1 name, I don't unset immidiatly, but only after another result is found, hence the `$b`.

It's quantity is increased if a dupe is found, on the key of the main loop.

```
$copy = $backpack_items['items'];

foreach($backpack_items['items'] as $k => $v){
  $b = false;
  $s = '';
  $n = getItemName($schema_items, $v['defindex'], $s);

  foreach($copy as $k2 => $v2){
    if($n == getItemName($schema_items, $v2['defindex'], $s)){
      if(!$b){
        $b = $k;
      } else {
        unset($backpack_items['items'][$k2]);
        $backpack_items['items'][$k]['quantity'] += 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Now use your original loop, and the dupes should be removed.
```